# Want a specific value from webpage

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class = "foo">
   <span class = "foo2" > HeaderText</span>
   <br>
   "
        TEXT I WANT"
```

I have been trying to get it in JS.

```
var NEEDED= document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].textContent
```

Also tried foo2 and innerText, innerHTML

I just don't know how to call something that isn't tied directly to an ID or Class

Comment: Are you trying to get the text node that is a direct ascendant of the `<div class="foo">` ?

Comment: How so? I'm pretty new to this environment as a whole. Its from a specific website with lots of products and it was just to make my job a little easier on data input.

Comment: Impossible to say without the needed information about the requirements / rules for parsing. All I can say is that the accepted answer is *really* brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is going to be very difficult if the HTML is subject to change. Even nodes that aren't surrounded by an HTML element are still childNodes of it's parent, so you can get this by looking at:

```
var needed = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].childNodes[4].nodeValue;
```

You might need to write a function that filters through all of the childNodes and finds one with `nodeType` 3 (text nodes), then ignore all of the ones that are just blank whitespace.

```js
var needed = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].childNodes[4].nodeValue;
document.write("The text is: " + needed);
```

```html
<div class = "foo">
   <span class = "foo2" > HeaderText</span>
   <br>
   TEXT I WANT
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I apparently can't upvote you but if I get enough points or whatever I'll be sure to give you a bump